# Check if value is empty javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

After submitting I want the redirect the users to a different page with the value of the input in the url. Now, when there is no value I want that it does nothing (return false). How can I do this?

My current code:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="searchInput">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search anything you want..." name="search" id="search" />

    <button name="btnsearch" id="btnsearch" onclick=" window.location = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/search/index")?>/'+document.getElementById('search').value; return false;">
        Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Ignoring the pretty rude comment above, Why don't you get php to do this for you?

Comment: It sound like you need to do the redirect after the submit. Seems like that is something that needs to be done in PHP not in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways to do that.
With JavaScript:

```js
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["nameField"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="nameField">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Or you can use the HTML5 required attribute:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>HTML 5 Form Validation</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="">
  Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now its up to you! :D

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with HTML *required* attribute. It looks better then hanling it with javascript. Just like this:

http://jsbin.com/xumaxilowo/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<form action="">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: That would change the GET that it is now to a POST though? This may not be desired behaviour

Answer (score 1):

this is the JS solution, no post will occour on server. (but this code needs to be in a php file)

```
<form action="" method="post" class="searchInput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search anything you want..." name="search" id="search" />

  <button name="btnsearch"
          id="btnsearch" 
          type="button"
          onclick="redirect();"
  >Search</button>
</form>
```

and here the js

```
function redirect() {
  var value = document.getElementById('search').value;
  if (value !== '') {
    window.location = '<?php echo base_url("index.php/search/index")?>/' +
                      document.getElementById('search').value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in this year and looking for the answer you can use
Note: It returns `true` if the array is empty, for this special edge case you can always check `array.length`;

```
return new Boolean(array) && array.length > 0;
```

For more information check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean